# How can I set or override Blazor default hub options .NET8

Tags: blazor, signalr, .net-8.0

Does anyone know how I can override or set the default hub options in .NET 8? Looking at MS documentation, it seems that I should be able to just add the app.MapBlazorHub() line with options after app.MapRazorComponents in program.cs per [ASP.NET Core Blazor SignalR guidance](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/fundamentals/signalr.md#blazor-hub-options) and [Blazor hub options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0#blazor-hub-options)
. When I try to add something like below

```
app.MapBlazorHub(options =>
{
    options.TransportSendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
```

I receive the following error about multiple endpoints being matched.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> Blazor initializers
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(Span`1 candidateState) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Does anyone know how I can override these options or the HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions for the default hub, _blazor, in .NET 8?

I can reproduce this by creating a new blank .NET 8 project and adding the above line.

I ask because I have these options overridden in a .NET6 project using the app.UseEndpoints with no problem

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
    {
        options.TransportSendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

I tried using the same method I used previous in .NET6 and am experiencing the error I described in the post for ambiguous endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dotnet 8 Blazor you can configure HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions like this :

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .Add(convention =>
    {
        var meta = convention.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(e => e is HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions);
        if (meta is HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions options)
        {
            options.TransportSendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        }
    });
```

for CircuitOptions and HubOptions :

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents()
.AddCircuitOptions(circuitOptions =>
{
    circuitOptions.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 100;
})
.AddHubOptions(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});
```

Comment: I tried this out in my application and it worked great. Thanks for the information!